githubのADODBDataAccessAPIのエラー処理がどう実行されているのかわからない
https://github.com/rickmanalexander/ADODBDataAccessAPI.git
の関数を抜き出して使用しているのですが、
このうち、　Module→AdoUtilities.basのGetFieldValueDefaultという以下の関数を使用した時に
DbErrorsのところで「オブジェクトがありません」というエラーが発生します。
こちらのDbErrorsというオブジェクトが、このAPIの中のどこで作成されているのかわかりません。
クラスモジュールにもこの名前のクラスはなく、DbErrors.basをVBEに入れても変わりませんでした。
DbErrorsを使うにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？
Public Function GetFieldValueOrDefault(ByVal rs As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal fieldNameOrIndex As Variant) As Variant
    DbErrors.GuardExpression Not (VarType(fieldNameOrIndex) = vbInteger Or VarType(fieldNameOrIndex) = vbLong Or VarType(fieldNameOrIndex) = vbString), _
                             ThisWorkbook.VBProject.name & "AdoUtilities.GetFieldValueOrDefault", "'fieldNameOrIndex' must be of Type 'Integer', 'Long', or 'String'"
    On Error Resume Next
    GetFieldValueOrDefault = rs.Fields(fieldNameOrIndex).value
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

